# Jquery Multidimensional Array or Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need to create an Object (or Array) with this format:

> obj["Home"] = 10
>
> obj["Car"] = 20
>
> obj["Music"][0]= 2
>
> obj["Music"][1]= 20
>
> obj["Music"][2]= 35
>
> obj["blabla"] = 15

and have option to add:

> obj["Home"] += 5 -> result -> 15
>
> obj["Music"][1] += 2 -> result -> 22

But my code don't work.

Comment: Where do you define your `obj` ?

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an object `obj`.

Property `Home` - `Car` and `blabla` are numbers

Property `Music` is an array. You have to initialize it with `obj["Music"] = [];`

```js
let obj = {};

obj["Home"] = 10;
obj["Car"] = 20;
obj["Music"] = [];
obj["Music"][0]= 2;
obj["Music"][1]= 20;
obj["Music"][2]= 35;
obj["blabla"] = 15;

console.log(obj);

obj["Home"] += 5;
obj["Music"][1] += 2;

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: OK, only a question. How add ( obj["Music"] = []; ) only the first time? Example: if(obj["Music"] == "undefinied"){obj["Music"] = [];}else{obj["Music"][0] = 10;}

Comment: @Diegs The first time of what ? The code is not in a loop

Comment: I use a function: var Calcoli ={};

$( document ).ready(function() {
 add_array("Test", '+', 15, "");
 add_array("Test1", '+', 40, 1);

});

function add_array(keys, op, value, i) {

    if (Calcoli[keys] == "" || Calcoli[keys] == "undefined" || isNaN(Calcoli[keys])) {
  Calcoli[keys] =0;
   }

 if (i != ""){
  if (Calcoli[keys][i] == "" || Calcoli[keys][i] == "undefined" || isNaN(Calcoli[keys][i])) {
   
   Calcoli[keys] = [];
  }
  if (op == "+"){ 
   Calcoli[keys][i] += value;
  }
 }else{
  if (op == "+"){
   Calcoli[keys] += parseInt(value);
 
  }
 }

}

Comment: @Diegs I don't understand what you need